# How to start jenkins on different port rather than 8080 using command prompt in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, jenkins, war, command-prompt

I have jenkins.war and I started it from command prompt in Windows as:

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

It was started well and easily browsed as `http://localhost:8080`

I want to start on 9090 port. How can I do that?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Use the following command at command prompt:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
```

If you want to use https use the following command:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpsPort=9090
```

Details are [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/initial-settings/)

Comment: Hi, I did this but after a reboot it reverted to 8080 again, is there a way to change the setting permanently?

Comment: @SteveGreen: The above mentioned commands are starting Jenkins from the command line. This is not a permant configuration. It is possible to save this command in a batch file and launch that file during startup, e.g. in an autostart folder.

Comment: It lefts old 8080 and now new 9090 both are working now

Comment: @RiponAlWasim is it standard way if i use `net start jenkins` command to start/stop jenkins services.

Answer (score 94):

Open the `jenkins.xml` in the jenkins home folder (usually `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`) and change the port number:
`httpPort=xxxx`

to
`httpPort=yyyy`

then restart the service. it should change the setting permanently.

Comment: Just restarting the service should suffice.

Comment: I do not see this file

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that 'jenkins.xml' is the one located in the same folder as jenkins.exe.  Not the one that you may have copied to folder pointed to by environment variable 'JENKINS_HOME'

Comment: This file was called `jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml` for me.

Comment: I would like to add that if you are not able to edit the jenkins.xml file on Windows for some reason, drag the file to your desktop. It will let you edit it there. Once you make the changes, drag the file back into the installation directory and restart the service. Big thanks to Prasad for the answer.

Comment: @Jubl: You're a lifesaver! Despite changing the default instance port upon initial Jenkins configuration, verifying that `jenkins.xml` had the correct `httpPort`, and restarting the Windows service, it still didn't work. Dragging the file to my desktop (which then reverted the default port back to 8080), editing it, putting it back into the installation folder, and then restarting the service made it work.

Answer (score 93):

With **Ubuntu 14.4** I had to change the file **/etc/default/jenkins**

E.g.

```
   #HTTP_PORT=8080
   HTTP_PORT=8083
```

and restart the service

> `service jenkins restart`

Comment: sadly this seems to not have any effect.it still says fail, port 8080 in use when I change to another port

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04 too

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart jenkins` restarts the service, too.

Comment: I changed the port to 80 (because it is not being used by any program), but after i restart the service, the status is active but I can't open it from browser. Do you know what's wrong?

Answer (score 49):

In CentOS/RedHat (assuming you installed the `jenkins` package)

`vim /etc/sysconfig/jenkins`

```
....
# Port Jenkins is listening on.
# Set to -1 to disable
#
JENKINS_PORT="8080"
```

change it to any port you want.

Comment: This is not working in amazon linux instance. I changed the port restarted jenkins but still listening to same port.

Answer (score 13):

**On Windows (with Windows Service).**

Edit the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.xml` with **8083** if you want 8083 port.

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8083</arguments>
```

Answer (score 10):

For the benefit of Linux users who find themselves here: I found /etc/sysconfig/jenkins has a JENKINS_PORT="8080", which you should probably change too.

Answer (score 8):

On Debian 11 it ignores **/etc/default/jenkins** file.
Instead you open **/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service** file and replace http-port there in the string:

```
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=8080"
```

Comment: tx. only this solution save me

Comment: Works with Ubuntu 20.04

`sudo nano /etc/default/jenkins` > Change the port > `systemctl daemon-reload` > `sudo service jenkins restart`

Answer (score 6):

In  *nix 
In CentOS/RedHat

vim /etc/sysconfig/jenkins

```
# Port Jenkins is listening on.
# Set to -1 to disable
#
JENKINS_PORT="8080"
```

In windows  open XML file 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.xml

```
<executable>%BASE%\jre\bin\java</executable>
  <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --**httpPort=8083**</arguments>
 i made  above bold  to show you change then 
 <executable>%BASE%\jre\bin\java</executable>
  <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8083</arguments>
```

now you have to restart  it doesnot work unless you restart
http://localhost:8080/restart
then after restart 
http://localhost:8083/
all  should  be well  so looks like  the  all above response which says it does not work  We have restart.

Answer (score 5):

For `Fedora`, `RedHat`, `CentOS` and alike, any customization should be done within `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` instead of `/etc/init.d/jenkins`. The purpose of the first file is exactly the customization of the second file.

So, within `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`, there is a the `JENKINS_PORT` variable that holds the port number on which Jenkins is running.

Answer (score 5):

Correct, use --httpPort parameter. If you also want to specify the $JENKINS_HOME, you can do like this:

```
java -DJENKINS_HOME=/Users/Heros/jenkins -jar jenkins.war  --httpPort=8484
```

Answer (score 5):

To change the default port of 8080. All you need to do:

1. Goto Jenkins folder present in C:\Program Files (x86)
2. Open a notepad or text pad and run them as administrator and then try opening the jenkins.xml file present in the jenkins folder.
3. Change the port number as below:
   `<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=9090</arguments>`
4. Click Save.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following two lines after DAEMON_ARGS in the file `/etc/init.d/jenkins`

HTTP_PORT=8010  
JENKINS_ARGS="--httpPort=$HTTP_PORT"

Answer (score 4):

If you have configured jenkins on ec2 instance with linux AMI and looking to change the port.
Edit the file at

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
```

Edit

```
JENKINS_PORT="your port number"
```

Exit vim

```
:wq
```

Restart jenkins

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```

Or simply start it, if its not already running

```
sudo service jenkins start
```

To verify if your jenkins is running on mentioned port

```
netstat -lntu | grep "your port number"
```

Comment: it does not work for me. Jenkins refuses to start on any port except for 8080.

Comment: It was my bad, it works. I had no Custom TCP Rule on aws for the other port. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can call

```
java -jar jenkins.war --help
```

to see a list of all available parameters.

Answer (score 2):

On OSX edit file:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.46.1/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist
```

and edit port to you needs.

Answer (score 1):

Open Command Prompt as Administrator in Windows .
Go to the directory where Jenkins is installed.
and stop the Jenkins service first, using **jenkins.exe stop**

type the command to change the port using, **java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090** (enter the port number you want to use).

and at-last, restart the Jenkins services, using **jenkins.exe restart**

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS: 14.2.1 (23C71) [sonoma]
The following command does not work for java version < 11

> java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090

So, first I installed jenkins with

> brew install jenkins-lts

And then edited the homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist file which is located under the following folder.

> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.426.2

Change the port of your choice and save the file.

```
        ...
        <string>--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1</string>
        <string>--httpPort=9090</string>
        ...
```

Then run

> brew services restart jenkins-lts

And its done.

Answer (score -1):

Change the '/etc/init.d/jenkins' shell

```
check_tcp_port "http" "$HTTP_PORT" "8080" || return 1
```

Change `8080` to whichever you want

Comment: 1. There is no /etc directory in Windows. 2. This is only a check if the port is already in use. You can change it in Ubuntu/Debian in /etc/default/jenkins: HTTP_PORT=9090