# How to deploy tomcat web apps with Jenkins installed

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, xampp, web-deployment

I have XAMPP inc Tomcat installed on a win machine.  It was working fine when url of `my domain.com/webapps/appName` was entered form another machine as well as the local machine.

I then installed Jenkins and can no longer access the apps - I assume it's because of port 8080 bt I don't enough enough to work out a solution.

I tried chaining the jenkins port - [How to start jenkins on different port rather than 8080 using command prompt in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265277/how-to-start-jenkins-on-different-port-rather-than-8080-using-command-prompt-in) - this works but jenkins is now on both 9090 and 8080.

Can anyone help please?
Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that you started a second Jenkins instance on port 9090 while an instance was already running on port 8080? Did you try to kill both (or reboot) and then start Jenkins again?

Comment: @DavidLevesque - that is a possibility.  I'll reboot the entire system to check.

Comment: @DavidLevesque - after pc reboot jenkins in still on port 8080 and 9090 results in a cannot be found error.

Comment: Did you install Jenkins as a Windows service (i.e. using the Windows installer)?

Comment: @DavidLevesque - yes, I believe so.  I followed the online tutorial.  I've just rebooted again after running the httpPort= command to see if I can get into the tomcat admin page and it now strangely works however access to jenkins on 9090 yields not found

Comment: I think the above occurred when tomcat was started before jenkins.  When i stopped tomcat i was able to view jenkins on 8080 again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed Jenkins as a Windows service (which is the case if you installed it using the Windows installer) you need to edit the port in Jenkins' config file `jenkins.xml`, located in the root of the Jenkins installation directory.

The answer you linked to only applies if you run Jenkins from a command prompt, not if it is installed as a Windows service.

Comment: That makes sense - my mistake :)
Would you happen o know where I need to change the port within the config file?  Majority of it seems to be for hudson permissions and there's not obvious port=8080 type thing.

Comment: Look for the string `--httpPort=`

Comment: Yeah, that's not there.  For a config file it doesn't seem to have a  lot going on.  It is the config.xml located within the installation folder? C:/Prgram File/Jenkins/config.xml

Comment: I don't think so, it should be called `jenkins.xml`.

Comment: aha :) Found it, changed it, restarting it, may jump for joy in two mins or so (Old machine) :)