# No credentials for preemptive authentication - port is returning -1

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm trying to trigger a job in Jenkins from java server.
Jenkins is running on port 80 but when the Preemptive Auth is executing then creds are null because port returning as -1

```
if (authScheme != null) {
                creds =
                        credsProvider.getCredentials(new AuthScope(
                                targetHost.getHostName(),
                                targetHost.getPort()));
                if (creds == null) {
                    throw new HttpException("No credentials for preemptive authentication");
                }
```

I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265277/how-to-start-jenkins-on-different-port-rather-than-8080-using-command-prompt-in)
 on how to change the port that jenkins is using and also this [link2](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) that explain that when not using a port (because of using https) it should be set to -1.

in the server there is a properties file that holds the Jenkins URL. after editing it to specific call port 80 (instead of just dropping it) then the trigger executed, but because of a mechanism that checking the job status (that it finish running) the next call is getting failed because the port is -1.

is there a way to see the port before changing?
what else can I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a definition of Jenkins URL in Jenkins management, what is the value there? with port 80?

Comment: Nice catch, there was no port 80 there, so I add it, but still the second call is getting -1. Maybe it will help other though