# How do we configure the jenkins url without port number for Windows Service installation method?

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins Version: 2.121.1

I installed the Jenkins server as a "Windows Service" and clueless to hide the port number from the Jenkins URL.

I attempted to provide the Jenkins URL pattern like "http://mydomain/jenkins", Still No luck.

As I know that, Jenkins war deployment with tomcat and port redirect will resolve this. But, I need to accomplish this for "Windows Service" installation.

Any help on this regard.

Comment: were you able to solve this. I am into similar situation and searching for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you try editing the jenkins.xml to run in the required 80 port - [How to start jenkins on different port rather than 8080 using command prompt in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265277/how-to-start-jenkins-on-different-port-rather-than-8080-using-command-prompt-in/28695948)

Comment: My question not to start with another port. How do I eliminate the port number from the url

Comment: ok, hope this helps - https://www.calvinallen.net/running-jenkins-on-port-80-under-windows/