# How to start Jenkins on a specific port after stopping?

Tags: jenkins, configuration, continuous-integration

I want to start Jenkins on 9090,

I searched for it and I saw the solutions:
[like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265277/how-to-start-jenkins-on-different-port-rather-than-8080-using-command-prompt-in)

And as in the answer I start it with

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
```

It worked good. But, when I stop Jenkins with the command

```
jenkins.exe stop
```

And start it again with command:

```
jenkins.exe start
```

It starts on 8080 instead of 9090 again. Whenever I run it with `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090`
everytime I need to install jenkins again and again. I just want to use simple start and stop commands as in the example without going to 8080.

Why does it happen or how can I configure it to start and stop with `jenkins.exe start/stop` always on 9090 ?

Note:I am using Windows

Comment: [Answered already here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23769478/598141). Also, jenkins.exe start is not the same as java -jar jenkins.war

Answer (score 0):

Configure Windows environment variable `JENKINS_HOME`

Default `JENKINS_HOME` is `C:\Users\<username>\.jenkins`

If you navigate to this path, you can find all your jobs, workspaces, all the stuff you had created earlier in Jenkins.

Now, when you install Jenkins on port 9090 (or any port) using command `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090`, Jenkins picks up "JENKINS_HOME" variable and all your stuff is loaded from previous installation.